# How to read a single char from the console in Java (as the user types it)?

Tags: java, input, console

Is there an easy way to read a single char from the console as the user is typing it in Java? Is it possible? I've tried with these methods but they all wait for the user to press *enter* key:

```
char tmp = (char) System.in.read();
char tmp = (char) new InputStreamReader(System.in).read ();
char tmp = (char) System.console().reader().read();           // Java 6
```

I'm starting to think that System.in is not aware of the user input until *enter* is pressed.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

What you want to do is put the console into "raw" mode (line editing bypassed and no enter key required) as opposed to "cooked" mode (line editing with enter key required.)  On UNIX systems, the 'stty' command can change modes.

Now, with respect to Java... see [Non blocking console input in Python and Java](http://www.darkcoding.net/software/non-blocking-console-io-is-not-possible/).  Excerpt:

> If your program must be console based,
>   you have to switch your terminal out
>   of line mode into character mode, and
>   remember to restore it before your
>   program quits. There is no portable
>   way to do this across operating
>   systems.

One of the suggestions is to use JNI.  Again, that's not very portable.  Another suggestion at the end of the thread, and in common with the post above, is to look at using [jCurses](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/).

Comment: JCurses is not very portable either.... From the JCurses README: "JCurses consists of two parts: the plattform independent part,
and plattform dependent part, that consists of a native shared library making primitive input and output operations available to the first part."

Comment: @RyanFernandes sounds quite portable to me - single tool that can be run on multiple systems (using different dependencies)

Answer (score 31):

You need to knock your console into raw mode. There is no built-in platform-independent way of getting there. [jCurses](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/) might be interesting, though.

On a Unix system, this might work:

```
String[] cmd = {"/bin/sh", "-c", "stty raw </dev/tty"};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd).waitFor();
```

[For example, if you want to take into account the time between keystrokes, here's sample code to get there.](https://web.archive.org/web/20161108171332/http://li367-160.members.linode.com/nikoschwarz/how-to-take-the-time-between-keystrokes-into-account-when-making-a-key-1/)

Comment: Worked fine for me under Linux

Comment: Worked on Mac as well. You probably want to mention that `stty cooked </dev/tty` should be run when the program needs to revert to buffered mode, and definitely before the program exits.

Comment: @Kelvin according to the code sample linked by the above answer, it should be `stty sane </dev/tty` at the end to revert: do you know maybe what's the practical difference between `sane` and `cooked`? Thanks!

Comment: @morgwai thanks for mentioning `sane`; I was unfamiliar with it. It looks like `sane` is better than `cooked` but that's just my intuition after reading the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stty.1.html). I don't understand the details well enough - too many flags! Also, found [this discussion](https://github.com/ghaerr/elks/issues/522) also expressing confusion; now I don't feel so bad :)

Comment: @Kelvin motivated by your man page reading I've found `--save` option ;-) It outputs all the current settings, that can be later used to restore the current config. I guess, that's the safest way, but requires some output capturing.

Answer (score 23):

I have written a Java class [RawConsoleInput](http://www.source-code.biz/snippets/java/RawConsoleInput) that uses [JNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access) to call operating system functions of Windows and Unix/Linux.

- On Windows it uses `_kbhit()` and `_getwch()` from msvcrt.dll.
- On Unix it uses `tcsetattr()` to switch the console to non-canonical mode, `System.in.available()` to check whether data is available and `System.in.read()` to read bytes from the console. A `CharsetDecoder` is used to convert bytes to characters.

It supports non-blocking input and mixing raw mode and normal line mode input.

Comment: How heavily has this been tested/stress-tested?

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Stress-testing is difficult for console input. I think, in this case it would be more important to test it in various environments (different Windows/Linux versions, 64/32 bit, Linux via SSH, Telnet, serial port or desktop console, etc.). So far I only use it in my private test tools. But the source code is relatively small, compared to other solutions (like JLine2 which uses Jansi). So there is not much that can go wrong. I wrote it, because JLine2 does not support single character input without blocking.

Comment: That's what I meant by stress-tested -- it's probably the wrong word; my bad. Anyway, nice! I've stolen^H^H^H^H^H^Hused it in a project of mine for school and it helped a bunch.

Comment: Hey - this class looks great. However: I cannot get it to work.. how am I supposed to use it? I have encountered System.in blocking until I press CTRL+D (on Linux) and now I read about console modes and the likes. I think your RawConsoleInput is what I am looking for - but how do I use it?

Comment: @Igor Just call RawConsoleInput.read(boolean) to read a keyboard character. It's documented in the source code (RawConsoleInput.java).

Comment: @Christiand'Heureuse: thanks! I had posted the comment, but after a while I found out how it works. Thank you! It works quite well in a linux terminal (have not tried it on Windows (yet)).

Comment: Very useful.  You might want to add a simple example, e.g.

`public static void main(String[] args) {
  RawConsoleInput GC = new RawConsoleInput();
  int CharRead = 0;
  
  for (;;) {
      try {
          CharRead = GC.read(true);
      } catch (IOException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(RawConsoleInput.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }
      if (CharRead == -1 || CharRead == 27 || CharRead == 3 || CharRead == 4)    // ^c, ^d, or Esc)
          break;
      switch (CharRead) {
          case 
      }
  }
}
`

Comment: Nice... I got this working in a Windows command prompt and assume it works fine in Linux.  Unfortunately I can't get it to work in a Windows Cygwin (BASH) terminal, even if I switch `isWindows` to `false`.  Specifically it gives this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'c': Native library (win32-x86-64/c.dll) not found in resource path (.;jna-4.1.0.jar)
        at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:271) 
...
        at consolereader.RawConsoleInput.main(RawConsoleInput.java:64)

Comment: Adding the source code to an existing project results in the following error in Netbeans: `package com.sun.jna does not exist`, does this have any external dependencies? Openjdk8

Comment: @M.E. The [JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) jar will have to be added in addition to RawConsoleInput.java. Also JNA [deprecated `Pointer.SIZE` in version 5](https://github.com/kaitoy/pcap4j/issues/191) so we also need to replace that with `Native.POINTER_SIZE` on line 170.

Comment: @Thirdwater Thanks, I have updated the source code for the current JNA version 5.6.0.

Answer (score 18):

There is no portable way to read raw characters from a Java console.

Some platform-dependent workarounds have been presented above. But to be really portable, you'd have to abandon console mode and use a windowing mode, e.g. AWT or Swing.

Answer (score 15):

Use [jline3](https://github.com/jline/jline3):

Example:

```
Terminal terminal = TerminalBuilder.builder()
    .jna(true)
    .system(true)
    .build();

// raw mode means we get keypresses rather than line buffered input
terminal.enterRawMode();
reader = terminal .reader();
...
int read = reader.read();
....
reader.close();
terminal.close();
```

Comment: I found that RawConsoleInput based solutions didn't work on MacOS High Sierra; however, this works perfectly.

Comment: jline has practically all you need to create an interactive console/terminal system. It works great in Linux. For a more complete example look at: https://github.com/jline/jline3/blob/master/builtins/src/test/java/org/jline/example/Example.java . It has autocomplete, history, password mask, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I' ve done it using jcurses...

```
import jcurses.system.InputChar;
import jcurses.system.Toolkit;

//(works best on the local machine when run through screen)
public class readchar3 {
    public static void main (String[] args)
        {
            String st;
            char ch;
            int i;
            st = "";
            ch = ' ';
            i = 0;
            while (true)
                {
                        InputChar c = Toolkit.readCharacter();
                    ch = c.getCharacter();
                    i = (int) ch;
                    System.out.print ("you typed " + ch + "(" + i + ")\n\r");
                    // break on '#'
                    if (ch == '#') break;
                }
            System.out.println ("Programm wird beendet. Verarbeitung kann beginnen.");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[See This](https://github.com/devlinuxuser/Jkey/tree/main)

It calls _getch() function from c to read a single char without hitting Enter