# Java key listener in Commandline

Tags: java, command-line

Most demo showing keyevent in Swing, what is the equivalent in commandline?

Answer (score 12):

Swing is different from a command line environment in the sense that you have no *events* in a console window. A standard GUI deals with objects and events. A console has no such equivalent notion.

What you **do** have is a standard input (as well as a standard output), which you can read from. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066318/how-to-read-a-single-char-from-the-console-in-java-as-the-user-types-it) on how to read a single char from console (without waiting for a newline) - or rather, on how this isn't very easy to do in Java.

Of course, you can always do the reading asynchronously on a separate thread. i.e. the main thread will keep doing stuff, with a listener thread waiting on the I/O blocking call. But this can only be implemented and handled on the application level.

Answer (score 6):

you can use `BufferedReader` in a loop:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String line = "";

   while (line.equalsIgnoreCase("quit") == false) {
       line = in.readLine();

       //do something
   }

   in.close();
```

Answer (score 5):

`KeyListener` is only for swing classes.

To have an equivalent functionality in a command line app you can use the [***JNativeHook***](https://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/) library which accomplishes this via `JNI`. This will allow you to listen for global shortcuts or mouse motion that would otherwise be impossible using pure Java. You also do not need to use `Swing` or other GUI classes.

Comment: The "JNativeHook library" does not help if you want to handle "Ctrl+C" key combination - the program gets terminated in the usual way.

Comment: Note that JnativeHook requires X11 to work (at least up to the 2.1.0 version) according to this issue: https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook/issues/162. For example I tried to use it in a Docker container and it did not work.

Answer (score 5):

Following code will prevent the Ctrl+C combination to stop a CLI java program.

```
import sun.misc.Signal; 
import sun.misc.SignalHandler;

    Signal.handle(new Signal("INT"), new SignalHandler() {
      // Signal handler method
      public void handle(Signal signal) {
        System.out.println("Got signal" + signal);
      }
    });
```

Comment: What is a CLI Java program?