# Execute a KeyListener in a Java console app

Tags: java, swing, console-application, keylistener

I need to implement a Java class that implements `KeyListener`. However, I don't need a `JFrame` or another awt/swing-based class. I only need a console application in Java.

I guess that I need to register my listener somewhere to let it working. How can I do this in a simple console application? I only find GUI-based examples.

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005574/java-key-listener-in-commandline

Comment: @PeterJaloveczki I'm gettin' a look. Thank you!

Comment: I marked my question as duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`KeyListener` is not meant for console apps. What you could do is read one character at a time using `System.in.read()`

Another method  to have a sort of console `KeyListener` is by using the JNI. You can install a global keyboard hook and listen for keypress. The ***[JNativeHook](https://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/)***  library will be useful if you want to do it in this way. You do not need to use Swing or other GUI classes.

Comment: There is a comment by [Peter Jaloveczki](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1960804/peter-jaloveczki) to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005574/java-key-listener-in-commandline) post. What do you think about it?

Comment: @mat_boy that post talks about alternative techniques. not that actual `KeyListener` class can be used to do that....

Comment: @pinkpanther Yes, you are right! Is not the same, is not useful at all compared with the effectiveness of `KeyListener` interface. Maybe I have to lunch a JFrame and to hidden this frame to the user's sight!

Comment: @mat_boy Hiding the `JFrame` is also not possible as `KeyEvent` will only be generated if the `JFrame` has active focus

Comment: @ExtremeCoders Of course, I didn't reasoned about that! I think that I have no choice: I need a swing app!

Comment: @ExtremeCoders Thank you! I'm gettin' a look! It seems interesting.