# Recognize arrow keys in Java Scanner or Console application

Tags: java, console, java.util.scanner, user-input

I am writing a Java application that uses both `Scanner` and `Console` to get input from the user. I would like to add command history support so that the user can use the ARROW KEYS to search previous inputs (similar to a terminal). Is there a way to do this? Right now, when I use either the `Scanner` or the `Console`, I get weird symbols like `^[[A` when pressing the arrow keys.

I have read about `KeyListener` and `KeyEvent`, but my application does not use a GUI.

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you still use a key listener to listen to key stroke events and then use  the carriage return character to overwrite outputs like `^[[A` and display the command from the history?

Comment: But a `KeyListener` only works with GUI applications. I am not developing a GUI application.

Comment: See if this is useful.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005574/java-key-listener-in-commandline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question - +1'd.  On Windows, I would SetConsoleMode to change the console to take raw input, but on *Nix it looks like there is more work involved.  Unfortunately I don't have any code that I can show you right now, but have a look at this link and see if it helps.

http://www.darkcoding.net/software/non-blocking-console-io-is-not-possible/

Comment: Thanks for the link! This was very helpful. Jline is the way to go.