# How to call a method on user input in loop in java?

Tags: java, loops, sockets

I'm beginner in java programming, I wrote basic server which is in endless loop and starts new `Threads` as shown below.

```
while (true) {
                DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receive, receive.length);
                socket.receive(receivePacket);
                username = new String(data(receive));
                Thread t = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        clientHandler(receivePacket);
                    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
            t.start();
            threads.add(t);
            t.setName(username);
        }
```

Now my goal is to call method to `getThreadList` when I type anything in my console window. I've tried `Scanner` and `System.in.read()` but they stop whole loop, waiting for my input. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java key listener in Commandline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005574/java-key-listener-in-commandline)

Comment: @SergeiSirik Reader also waits for input, denying every next connections

Comment: Separate thread for a reader? And implementing something like ActionListner in Swing,  [Observer Pattern](https://www.baeldung.com/java-observer-pattern) ? Send events to the server thread only when you get something in the reader thread?

Comment: @SergeiSirik I will try that, but isn't there any less complicated way?