# Detect a key press in console

Tags: java

I want to execute a certain function when a user presses a key. This will be run in the console, and the code is in Java. How do I do this? I have almost zero knowledge of key presses/keydowns, so I could really use an explanation as well.

Comment: So, a reason for the down-vote would be nice. One could improve with some constructive criticism, with constructive being the key word here.

Comment: As a note, frameworks like `JNativeHook` can provide global hooks to the key events by going through the Windows API.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

If you want to play with the console, you can start with this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean exit = false;
        while (!exit) {
            System.out.println("Enter command (quit to exit):");
            String input = keyboard.nextLine();
            if(input != null) {
                System.out.println("Your input is : " + input);
                if ("quit".equals(input)) {
                    System.out.println("Exit programm");
                    exit = true;
                } else if ("x".equals(input)) {
                    //Do something
                }
            }
        }
        keyboard.close();
    }
}
```

Simply run ScannerTest and type any text, followed by 'enter'

Comment: Do I need to import any libraries for this?

Comment: Okay. I'll check and see

Comment: In my knowledge `keyboard.nextLine()` does not detect keypress. It return the line after user has pressed Enter.

Comment: Its more than wrong - it requires ENTER to actually pass input.

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question tbh. This just reads an entire line from standard input. This does not handle key events like keypress or keydown/keyup.

Answer (score 9):

You can't detect an event in the command line environment. You should provide a GUI, and then you can use the `KeyListener` class to detect a keyboard event.

Alternatively you can read commands from standard input and then execute a proper function.

Comment: The requirement is to do so in a command line, and I've been told that it can be done in C++. So, why not Java?

Comment: maybe because in C++ you have access to OS functions, while in Java you need a java ui to capture key press ? Here is a related thread : https://stackoverflow.com/a/4609067/4802862

Comment: Technically, you can add a global key listener hook using the windows api and listen for keypresses like that. There are frameworks like JNativeHook for that.