# Check if a key is pressed in console

Tags: java, keyboard, command-line-interface

I want to check - either by some method or event handler - if a user has pressed a key in a CLI application.

Something like that:

```
if(isWPressed)
    System.out.println("'W' is pressed");
if(isAPressed)
    System.out.println("'A' is pressed");
```

I've tried this answer:
[How do I check if the user is pressing a key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18037576/how-do-i-check-if-the-user-is-pressing-a-key)

But it didn't work and looking at imports I've noticed it uses awt, so it's not useful in CLI, where there are no windows to speak of. I also can't use `Scanner` for that (as suggested here: [Detect a key press in console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27381021/detect-a-key-press-in-console)) as if user would press multiple buttons - like `w` and `a` I need to know both of them are pressed.

Comment: Do you think this library might help? https://github.com/jline/jline3

Comment: It might be useful in future, but for this problem - I've glanced over it's javadoc and it doesn't seam to contain a way to achieve what I want.

Answer (score -2):

YOu need to use keylistener, it permits to get the key

```
Example 

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javaapplication7;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

/**
 *
 * @author wilso
 */
public class List implements KeyListener {

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

}
```

If you dont want to use awt, then you can use scanner  or Event

```
@Override
public void nativeKeyPressed(NativeKeyEvent e) {
    String temp = NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode());
    if (validHotKeys.contains(temp)) {
        if (!pressedHotKeys.contains(temp)) {
            pressedHotKeys.add(temp);
            System.out.println(pressedHotKeys.toString());
        }
    }
    if (validAlphaKeys.contains(temp)) {
        if (!pressedAlphaKeys.contains(temp)) {
            pressedAlphaKeys.add(temp);
            System.out.println(pressedAlphaKeys.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: He specified that he did not want to use awt in his question

Comment: It's not that I don't want to use awt - I cannot use awt

As for the second solution - sign - you need to expand on it. By googling I assume it's form JNativeHook library, which from what I see is poorly documented and does not show how `NativeKeyListener` can be used in console