# Read from keyboard the CANCEL character

Tags: java, io

How can I get the DEL char from keyboard?

If I use the I/O API I must wait the return to get the char
but so I always get the ASCII code 10 or 13...

Thanks.

Comment: Work with your problem description. Difficult to understand.

Comment: What is the CANCEL character? The "Escape" key?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066318/how-to-read-a-single-char-from-the-console-in-java-as-the-user-types-it

Answer (score 0):

Use [key Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html).

```
 public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke)
    {
    if(ke.getKeyChar()== ke.VK_DELETE)
      {
    //do something
      }
    }
```

Here is a [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) how you can do that.

Comment: Thanks, but I have to use the console.

Comment: I don't think you can do that from console because you have to hit ENTER to get anything from console.

Comment: Use Java [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) . It can get characters but i doubt about keys like del.

Comment: @xdevel2000, what do you intend to do by intercepting DEL?

Comment: @st0le, I intend make something like InputStreamReader cin = new InputStreamReader(System.in); cin.read(); and have the ASCII value of DEL key.

Comment: @xdevel2000, Don't re-invent the wheel.... Use `Scanner` or a `BufferReader` (has readLine()) function...it'll handle the DEL key aswell.