# How do I wait for and read a single key input in the Console?

Tags: java, input, console, key

I am creating a game, and just to get the logic down I am only using the console window to test the process.  I am prompting the user to hit either the 'd' or the 'p' key without requiring to press the Enter key.  If the user presses either one it will branch off to its subroutine.   How do I go about waiting for the input of a single key?

This is in Java.  Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Would be rather useful to know about what language you're using.

Comment: If you are using C#, try Console.Readline(). That will cause a console app to wait until the user enters a key stroke.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/1066318/965648

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to read a keypress without waiting for an "enter" or newline. Unfortunately this isn't really possible in Java, as detailed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066318/how-to-read-a-single-char-from-the-console-in-java-as-the-user-types-it?noredirect=1&lq=1). I wish I could help you more, but there aren't really any portable ways of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

`System.in.read()` is a blocking read on a single unsigned byte.

Answer (score 0):

Include the below line where your program want to wait to get input from user.

> DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(System.in); String string
>   = input.readLine();

For more information refer the below site

> http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-get-example/java-get-user-input.shtml
>   http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/85435

Comment: Is there no way to read a keypress?  I find it odd basic had a function to read keypresses and java does not