# Java how do you detect tab key press within a non-GUI application?

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a program that simulates the terminal tab completion. But I'm unsure of how to trap the tab key. This is a non gui application. I'm not looking for swing/awd actionlisteners

**Desired Result**

```
While(true)
//Some api to capture KeyEvent.VK_TAB (tab key)
System.out.print("You typed tab")
```

Comment: Using a non-standard console or JNA or JNI come to mind.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to read a single char from the console in Java (as the user types it)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1066318/207421)

Answer (score 3):

After some googling, i found that there are quite a few java libraries for handling console input. Some of them are:

[1. jLine](https://github.com/jline/)

[2. Lanterna](https://code.google.com/archive/p/lanterna/)

[3. Java Curses Library](https://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/)

[4. Charva](http://www.pitman.co.za/projects/charva/index.html)

[5. Blacken](https://code.google.com/archive/p/blacken/)

jLine have features like custom keybinds, tab completion, line editing etc.  jLine have method like readVirtualKey that reads a virtual key from the console e.g. VK_UP.

You can also implement auto complete functionality using tab key. You might have to implement your own **Completer** class for that. Have a look at the link given below, it clearly shows tab completion functionality. May be that is what you need.

https://jeszysblog.wordpress.com/2012/04/14/readline-style-command-line-editing-with-jline/