# How to capture keyboard event without Enter key in java/scala?

Tags: java, scala, keyboard-events

I'm writing a game based on terminal and I want capture keyboard event, such as w/a/s/d as direction of Up/Left/Below/Right, rather then `readLine` a input stream with a Enter key.

Besides, I have read swing package, it has some `KeyListener` interface but it seems must bind with swing UI.

Does there have pure keyboard event without other technology binding in java world?

Comment: this might help you https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html . other solution might be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11673782/using-java-how-to-detect-keypresses-without-using-gui-components

Comment: @XtremeBaumer, it bind with swing UI, I need a terminal friendly method.

Comment: then maybe this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30564519/java-read-key-from-console-without-press-enter-key ? there are some solutions if you look at suggested answers

Comment: what you want to look into is "raw" mode. The terminal by default does not give you any input unless you hit enter. You can adjust the configuration with the stty utility which you can call from java/scala. Here is an example of doing that https://github.com/jsuereth/streamerz/blob/1edd22e5d56a28655302ada2c6655232a4d63686/ansi/src/main/scala/com/jsuereth/ansi/Stty.scala.

Comment: @lucidd, it works with `new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))` and yours `Stty.bufferByCharacter()`.