# How to autocomplete tab user's input in console in Java

Tags: java, input, console

I can open a console input prompt to the user by using:

```
BufferedReader bufferRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String s = bufferRead.readLine();
```

Is there anyway to auto complete a user's input when they press tab?
For example, they type:

```
>>: eat app[press tab]
>>: eat apple
```

Because apple is a known word in my code.
Is there a way to do this without using libraries like JLine or JavaReadline

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9964995/java-how-do-you-detect-tab-key-press-within-a-non-gui-application

Comment: I wouldn't user a `BufferedReader`, it won't capture the individual key strokes..

Comment: I can't see any way to intercept the keystrokes from stdin.  You will need something that is much more lower level.