# BufferReader readline() method hangs for system.in

Tags: java

I am executing a simple java application in eclipse.

Sample code:

```
 BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String line;
    while((line = input.readLine()) != null && line.length() != 0) 
    {
    System.out.println("------"+line);
    }
```

In the above code the readline() method hangs when reading the last line of my input.
I have gone through some threads and understood that it waits for the end of line.
I don't want to give any '\n' or '\r' at the end of my input in the console. 
so how to handle this in the code.

Comment: Please clarify the problem all seems to be fine when testing. What is the expected output vs the output you got? To exit the loop I just hit enter without typing anything

Comment: Typically you send an EOF with `Ctrl-D`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066318/how-to-read-a-single-char-from-the-console-in-java-as-the-user-types-it

Answer (score 0):

How is the code to know when you are not going to type anything else unless you press enter?

There is no solution to this issue.  You need to re-think your use-case.