# Java Scanner: read immediately on keystroke

Tags: java

This might seem like a very simple problem, but I am unsure how to do it.

If I have Scanner attached to System.in, and want to return a token *immediately* upon pressing *any* button (i.e. not having to press enter to proceed), how can I set this up? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066318/how-to-read-a-single-char-from-the-console-in-java-as-the-user-types-it

Comment: That indeed seems to be it, I could not find it. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @chrsva.. What did you try?? that post is about your query only??