# Pure implementation of getline reading character by character in Scala

Tags: scala, getline

I've been trying to implement my own version of getline in Scala. I want to read character by character. The closest I have gotten is:

```
def in_string: List[Char] = {
io.Source.fromInputStream(System.in)
  .takeWhile(_ != '\n')
  .toList
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you do an identity map?

Comment: Eventually I will be mapping the value to an object

Comment: If there is an approach I can take without using System.in @sschaef

Comment: What's wrong with `System.in`?

Comment: Pure in a functional context means referential transparency. Reading an external input can allmost be considered as the definition of an impure function. So a pure implementation is impossible.

Comment: @RexKerr I want to use pure Scala and not fall back on java.

Comment: @MartinRing this is actually what I was thinking, but wanted to hear it from someone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "pure" you mean functional, see Martin Ring's comment.

If by "pure" you mean "no Java", again you can't with the above method, because `InputStream` is from Java (and whatever you do you're going to use some Java something somewhere).

It is theoretically possible to avoid `System.in`:

```
Console.readLine  // Reads a whole line for you
```

There's no sense taking this apart into characters and putting it back together into a line again.

Your bigger problem is actually reading character by character instead of line by line.  That's not easy to do with the tools given in Java, and since Scala is built atop the JVM, it can't really do any better.  See for example SO #[1066318](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066318).