# Java program that will tell if user input is a double or not

Tags: java, double

I need some code that will tell whether or not some user input is a `double`. If it is a `double`, I need it stored in the variable `degreeCelsius` and if it isn't, I need the program to exit. Overall, the program is going to take some `double` values and use them as degrees Celsius and convert them to degrees Fahrenheit. This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Lab4b
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        double degreeCelsius = 0.0;
        double degreeFahrenheit = 0.0;
        System.out.println("Celcius    | Fahrenheit");

        while(scan.next() != null)
            {    
//this is where I need the code. If you see any other errors, feel free to correct me
            //if (degreeCelsius = Double)
                    {
                        degreeCelsius = scan.nextDouble();
                    }
                else
                    {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                degreeFahrenheit = degreeCelsius * (9.0/5.0) + 32.0;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Formatting aside, there's a few things wrong here.  `scan.next() != null` is not a proper way to ensure that there are elements left in the scanner, and you do nothing with `degreeFahrenheit` after you calculate it.  My gut feeling tells me you need two separate methods for this.

Comment: We haven't been taught how to create multiple methods, it's for an intro to java class. I'm a beginner at this and would appreciate any help. Could I upload the instructions?

Comment: No, creating a Celsius/Fahrenheit converter is straightforward enough.  If you can't use two separate methods, then consider addressing the issue of not doing anything with `degreeFahrenheit` after it's calculated.

Comment: Don't understand you mean , if in `scan.nextDouble()` returns a String for example? it will throw an `InputMismatchException` if can't convert.

Answer (score 1):

Since you may *not* get a double entered, best to read in a String, then attempt to convert it to a double. The standard pattern is:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
double userInput = 0;
while (true) {
    System.out.println("Type a double-type number:");
    try {
        userInput = Double.parseDouble(sc.next());
        break; // will only get to here if input was a double
    } catch (NumberFormatException ignore) {
        System.out.println("Invalid input");
    }
}
```

The loop can't exit until a double has been entered, after which `userInput` will hold that value.

Note also how by putting the prompt inside the loop, you can avoid code duplication on invalid input.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to modify your while:

```
    while(scan.hasNextDouble()) {
        degreeCelsius = scan.nextDouble();
        degreeFahrenheit = degreeCelsius * (9.0/5.0) + 32.0;
        System.out.println(degreeCelsius + " in Celsius is " + degreeFahrenheit + " in Fahrenheit");

    }
```

Keep in mind that event with Scanner breaking up input by whitespace, you still *usually* need to press enter between entries due to Unix and Windows default terminal settings.

So here for more info:

[How to read a single char from the console in Java (as the user types it)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066318/how-to-read-a-single-char-from-the-console-in-java-as-the-user-types-it)

Comment: @Makoto I'm confused by your comment. If you enter a `1` then the output is `33.8`

Answer (score 0):

Use `Double.parse` method.  See doc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29).

Using the above method, parse the user input and catch the `NumberFormatException`.  Any user input that is not Double-parseable willthrow the exception inside which you can break the loop.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
while (scan.hasNext()) {
   if (scan.hasNextDouble()) {
      double d = scan.nextDouble();
      ...
   } else {
      ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below method to check if your input string is double or not.

```
public boolean isDouble(String inputString) {
    try {
            Double d=Double.parseDouble(inputString);
        return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TempConversion
{
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String degSymbol = "\u00b0"; // unicode for the 'degree' symbol 

        do {
            try {
                System.out.print("\nEnter temperature or press q to exit: ");
                String input = scan.next();
                if (input.equals("q") || input.equals(" ")) {
                    System.exit(0);
                } else {
                    double temp_input = Double.parseDouble(input);

                    System.out.printf("What unit of temp is %,.2f? " +
                                      "\nCelsius\nFarenheit\nKelvin: ", temp_input);
                    char unit_from = scan.next().toUpperCase().charAt(0);

                    System.out.printf("\nConvert %,.2f%s%c to what unit? " +
                                      "\nCelsius\nFarenheit\nKelvin: ", 
                                      temp_input, degSymbol, unit_from);
                    char unit_to = scan.next().toUpperCase().charAt(0);

                    String convert = Character.toString(unit_from) +
                                     Character.toString(unit_to);

                    switch(convert) {
                    case "CF": //celsius to farenheit
                        double temp_results = (9.0/5.0) * temp_input + 32;
                        System.out.printf("\nRESULT: %,.2f\u00b0%c = %,.2f\u00b0F\n", 
                                          temp_input, unit_from, temp_results);   
                        break;
                    case "FC": // farenheit to celsius
                        temp_results = (5.0/9.0) * (temp_input - 32);
                        System.out.printf("\nRESULT: %,.2f\u00b0%c =     %,.2f\u00b0C\n",
                                          temp_input, unit_from, temp_results);
                        break;
                    case "CK": //celsius to kelvin
                        temp_results = temp_input + 273.15;
                        System.out.printf("\nRESULT: %,.2f%s%c = %,.2f%sK\n", temp_input,
                                          degSymbol, unit_from, temp_results, degSymbol);
                        break;
                    case "FK": // farenheit to kelvin
                        temp_results = (temp_input + 459.67) * 5.0/9.0;
                        System.out.printf("\nRESULT: %,.2f%s%c = %,.2f%sK\n", temp_input,
                                          degSymbol, unit_from, temp_results, degSymbol);
                        break;
                    case "KF": // kelvin to farenheit
                        temp_results = temp_input * 9.0/5.0 - 459.67;;
                        System.out.printf("\nRESULT: %,.2f%s%c = %,.2f%sF\n", temp_input,
                                          degSymbol, unit_from, temp_results, degSymbol);
                        break;
                    case "KC": // kelvin to celsius
                        temp_results = temp_input - 273.15;
                        System.out.printf("\nRESULT: %,.2f%s%c = %,.2f%sC\n", temp_input,
                                          degSymbol, unit_from, temp_results, degSymbol);
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("\nERROR: One or more variables you entered " +
                                           "are invalid. Please try again.");
                        break;
                    } // ends switch
                } // ends else
            } catch (NumberFormatException ignore) {
                System.out.println("Invalid input.");
            }
        } while(true); //ends do
    } // ends main
} // ends class
```

Comment: Can you please beautify it by adding some more details to it