# How to pass argument shown as asterisk to main function of a Java application

Tags: java

I have a Java command line application which needs to take a username and password as arguments passed in the main function.

Is there a way to make the password shown as asterisk when the user types their password?

Thanks.

Comment: Not that I am aware.  This is the domain of the shell that the user is using...

Comment: It is possible, but this will depend on the terminal used. What are you using (DOS, Bash, etc.)?

Comment: DOS. Command Prompt on Windows OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way that I know of to pass a hidden password to the main method as a command line argument without some kind of wrapper program.

However, using [`System.console().readPassword()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html#readPassword%28%29) or [`System.console().readPassword(String fmt, Object... args)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html#readPassword%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) the program can read user input from the command line without showing what the user is typing.

**Edit:** I don't know of any existing thing in java that replaces all the characters in the password with asterisks as the user types them but doing such a thing would require making it so that the command line would send program the characters individually instead of all together at a line ending.
Nothing easy or portable but more information on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1066647/2341449).