# Java stop looping while press Enter

Tags: java, loops

So, I already have this code for looping while press Enter

```
boolean inputCheck = true;

inputCheck = true;
while(inputCheck ){
    System.out.println(For example this is main menu);
    System.out.println("Press Enter to back to Main Menu");

    balikMenu = scan.nextLine();
    if(balikMenu.isEmpty()) {
        inputCheck = true;
    }
}
```

My question is, is there any other method besides using the scan? I don't want to use any key other than the enter key and don't accept any input other than enter to get the boolean true.

Comment: in this case, the scan can read another input, how to make this scan readonly except the empty space, lol

Comment: See this answer to a different question
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25095049/4680700

Comment: How about a [KeyListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html) ?