# How to make the scanner read multiply numbers and print them without going down a row

Tags: java

I am new to java and I am trying to write the code as followed:
user inputs numbers one by one and the code needs to print right away each number and continue to receive the next number on the **same row**

this is my code so far:

```
        Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);
        String value = user.nextLine();
        String matrix = "";
        int point = 0;
        int pos = 0;
        while(pos <= 5)
        {
            if(isInteger(value))
            {
                System.out.print(matrix.substring(point) + "\t");
                matrix = matrix + value+",";
                point+=2;
                pos++;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print("Not a number");
            }
            value = user.next();
        }
```

but every time I input another number to the scanner when the program is running, it goes down to the next row. so after I type 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 the output is:

```
1
     2
     3
     4
     5
```

I want to make it like this:

```
1     2     3     4     5
```

is there a way to make the scanner read another number and still remain on the same line?

Comment: Maybe [Read every key pressed on console at a time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21069857/java-read-every-key-pressed-on-console-at-a-time) will give you some hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `nextInt()` instead of `nextLine()` as specified [here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29)

Comment: That will not consume the line break, but it is still there as the user confirms his input with <enter> IMO

Comment: @ifLoop nextInt returns int, so yes at first he will have to enter `1 2 3 4 5(enter character)`, but his program will print afterwards `1 2 3 4 5` all in one line without newline character at the end.

Comment: _but every time I input another number to the scanner when the program is running, it goes down to the next row_ That sounds as OP wishes to read them one by one while typing, not when confirmed with enter.

Comment: @ifLoop yes and his problem will be solved by using `nextInt()` because it will return an integer without a newline. His current solution employs reading the whole string typed in. If he switches to `nextInt()` and prints int instead of String then he will not get the newline character included.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Type in all your numbers and hit return");
    while (scanner.hasNext()) System.out.println(scanner.next());
}
```

The user inserts all numbers in one line. Afterwards you scan the input, integer per integer and print them. As separator I used space.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can input all the numbers at one line separated by space & hit enter,the output will be at one line.Check it out..

```
    int num; 
    int pos = 0;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Type all the integers and hit return :");

    while (pos < 5) {

         if(scanner.hasNextInt()) {

         num = scanner.nextInt();
         System.out.print(num + "\t");
         pos++;

     } else { 

             scanner.next();  
             System.out.print("Not an integer number! ");
         }
    }
```

### Example :

input : 1  2  3  4  5

output : 1    2    3    4    5

---

input : 1  2  3  M  5

output : 1    2    3    Not an integer number!    5