# What is System.in.read()

Tags: java

What is system.in.read() here, where can i find every detail and use of it and where it is in documentation? in classes or whaterver ?

```
char ch;
ch=(char)System.in.read();
System.out.println("you typed"+ch);
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#in ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.in` returns an `InputStream`. The method `read()` without parameters "Reads the next byte of data from the input stream." according to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

System.in is basic reading in:

```
Scanner suckItUp=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter your favorite soda: ");
String name=suckItUp.nextLine();
```

System.in is the InputStream.  It is usually connected the keyboard, but may also be connected to console.

[first, always head to the API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html)

Here's a nice link - [Java IO tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/system-in-out-error.html)

[How to read a single char from the console in Java (as the user types it)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066318/how-to-read-a-single-char-from-the-console-in-java-as-the-user-types-it)

[How can I read input from the console using the Scanner class in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871520/how-to-use-the-scanner-class-in-java)

Read up on this valuable topic. Java IO is super-important.

Answer (score 0):

`read()` is an instance method of the static variable named '`in`' of the `System` class