# java rerun program not working with do while loop

Tags: java, do-while

just started java, eclipse

I want the program to contine only if 'y' or 'Y' is pressed

if any other key is pressed end program

please help

```
import java.io.*;


public class TicketMaster{

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{

    char choice;

    do{
        choice ='\0'; //clear char
        System.out.println("First Test \t\t" + choice);

        //rerun program
        System.out.println("Run Program Again: ");
        choice = (char) System.in.read();

        //testing
        if(choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y')
            System.out.println("Contine \t\t" + choice);
        else
            System.out.println("End Program \t\t" + choice);


        System.out.println("\n\n\n");
    }
    while(choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y');


} //end main method
} //end class
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem appears to be that the program ends even though `'Y'` or `'y'` is entered.

The cause is that no input will be sent to Java until you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  This places an entire line of input and a newline character(s) on the input stream.

The first iteration of the `while` loop correctly recognizes the `'y'` or `'Y'`, but the next loop immediately runs and detects the newline character(s) which doesn't match.

Switch to using a [`Scanner` so you can can call `nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) to read an entire line of input at once, and you can extract the first character of the `String` to see if it's `'y'` or `'Y'`.  This will discard the newline character(s).

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
    if(choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y')
        System.out.println("Contine \t\t" + choice);
    else{
        System.out.println("End Program \t\t" + choice);
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

or this if you don't  want the program to exit completely, but just to break the while loop

```
    if(choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y')
        System.out.println("Contine \t\t" + choice);
    else{
        System.out.println("End Program \t\t" + choice);
        break;
    }
```

Comment: You still don't get a choice between each iteration. If you type yyyy and hit enter, the loop will repeat 4 times, then the execution (or loop) ends.

Answer (score 0):

Since `read` only reads a single character from the `InputStream` you will need to manually consume the newline character

```
choice = (char) System.in.read();
System.in.read(); // added - consumes newline
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, Java doesn't usually support what I think you're trying to do, which I believe is to detect a key press on the console, without pressing enter.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066318/how-to-read-a-single-char-from-the-console-in-java-as-the-user-types-it) for discussions on how this might be achieved.