# How to print characters as user inpt them in console and stop when user enters enter character java

Tags: java, input, character, java.util.scanner, stringbuffer

I am trying to write a method that prints out whatever character the user is entering character by character appended with the previous ones as he enters and throws an exception when he presses enter. I have written the following code but when i enter, it appends what ever character I have written and does not throw an exception.  I would appreciate your help and suggestion.

```
public static void inputM(StringBuffer a) throws EntExc, IOException{
              char c;
       String m;
    while(true){
       Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

       m=s.next();
       c=m.charAt(0);

        if(c=='\r'){
            throw new EntExc();
        }
        System.out.println(a.append(m));
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read a single char from the console in Java (as the user types it)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066318/how-to-read-a-single-char-from-the-console-in-java-as-the-user-types-it)

Comment: here is what you need http://ideone.com/KXmybg

Comment: yes this one works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues here. First `s.next()` grabs a whitespace-delimited token and returns the entire token as a single string. Second, because `Scanner` uses whitespace as a delimiter, it will never return `\r`, it will just skip it and read the next token.

Why not use `s.readLine()` and simply echo the whole line? While it won't process characters as they are entered (`Scanner` can't really do this, it always buffers lines), it will be closer to your described requirement.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066318/how-to-read-a-single-char-from-the-console-in-java-as-the-user-types-it?lq=1

Comment: Thanks! yes that does make it better but still, isn't there a way to actullay print them char by char and not get it line by line?

Comment: Thanks for the link. but still when I do readline it does not seem to get '\r' char. how can I know the user pressed enter then?

Comment: @Ana When `readLine()` returns, it means the user pressed enter. You don't really have to check for it.

Comment: @Ana As for printing char-by-char, check out the linked question I posted.