# Java reading keyboard input

Tags: java, command-line

Is there a way to read input from the keyboard using command line *without* that input being displayed to the command line using java?

example i want the user to be able to type in random chars and then the system can process these chars without them begin displayed to the screen like a scanner or `System.console().readLine;` would.

Edit:

1. I need to read the raw input as chars, not something that requires the user to press enter after their input string

2.similar to what this code does in Haskell

```
hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering
hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering
hSetEcho stdin False
)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066318/how-to-read-a-single-char-from-the-console-in-java-as-the-user-types-it

Comment: Sorry to ask, but you are the third person i've seen this past week asking something like this and none ever explained why they want this. Just curious.

Comment: I can't speak for the others who have posted about this as I didn't know anyone else has had this problem, but I'm writing a simple game that takes the users input via one thread and using another the computer generates random chars at decreasing intervals to a buffer,for the user to guess, if they match up the user gets a point, once 10 chars are in the buffer the game stops. Initially it was the computer generating both the buffer chars and the guesses but now i want to modify the code so the user can do input, i have done this in haskell but was wondering if there is a similar way in java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No I don't think that there is a way to do this with the command-line. But instead you could use a [JFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) and add a [`CaretListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/caretlistener.html) to it.

Comment: Ok thanks, couldn't find anything myself just needed to know if i was missing something.

Comment: @user4301818 **Just Curious** Why do you want to do this?

Comment: See my above comment to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use [`java.io.Console.readPassword()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Console.html#readPassword--).

Comment: wouldn't that require the user to press enter after the input? Sorry i should have said i need raw input

Comment: Yes, if you don't want that, you could write a GUI application instead of a command-line application. There's no way to read individual characters from the console without echoing them as far as I know.