# KeyEvents in console?

Tags: java, keylistener

I am attempting to build a text based platformer, but they keyboard input isnt working... Help?

Here is the code theoretically it should move the little x whenever you press the arrow keys.

```
import java.awt.event.*;
public class MAIN implements KeyListener{
    private static int renderSizeX = 100;
    private static int renderSizeY = 25;
    public static String keyInput="";

    public static void main(String[] args){

        point player = new point(50,10,'X');
        while(true==true){
            m.sleep(160);
            if(keyInput=="38")//up key
                player.moveY(1);
            if(keyInput=="40")//down key
                player.moveY(-1);
            if(keyInput=="37")//< key
                player.moveX(-1);
            if(keyInput=="30")//> key
                player.moveX(1);
            m2.render(new point[]{player});
        }
    }

public static int windowX(){ return renderSizeX;}

public static int windowY(){ return renderSizeY;}
//KEYBOARD INPUT!
     public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){
          keyInput = e.getKeyCode()+"";
     }

     public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
     }

     public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
          keyInput = "";
     }
}
```

I dont think there is anything wrong with my rendering class and point class but i will show them as well.

```
public class point{
    int x, y;
    char letter;
    public point(int inX, int inY, char letterRepresent)
    {
        x = inX;
        y = inY;
        letter=letterRepresent;
    }

    public char getChar(){return letter;}
    public int getX(){return x;}
    public int getY(){return y;}
    public void moveX(int ammount){x+=ammount;}
    public void setX(int location){x=location;}
    public void moveY(int ammount){y+=ammount;}
    public void setY(int location){y=location;} 
}

 public class m{

     //sleep method
    public static void sleep(int milli){
         try {
            Thread.sleep(milli);                 //1000 milliseconds is one second.
         } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
             Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
         }


public class m2

{
        public static void render(point[] input){
            System.out.print("\f");//Clears screen
            for(int y = 0; y < MAIN.windowY(); y++){
            for(int x = 0; x < MAIN.windowX(); x++){
                char found = ' ';

                for(int i = 0; i < input.length;i++){
                    if( input[i].getY() == y && input[i].getX() == x ){//checks to see if list of points contains a point at current x and y position
                        found = input[i].getChar();
                    }
                }
                System.out.print(found);//prints char if found else prints space
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: A KeyListener is used to listen to keyboard events happening on graphical awt components. Not in the console. And a KeyListener has to be added to something that emits KeyEvents. Otherwise, it will never get called. To read from the console, use `System.in` and learn Java IO. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/cl.html

Comment: Should I use the scanner class? or will that not work for what I am tryng to do?

Comment: I don't think anything in the standard API would allow you doing what you want to do if you want to stay console-based.

Comment: Change your console to [raw mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066318/how-to-read-a-single-char-from-the-console-in-java-as-the-user-types-it) or look into native key listeners (which can give the illusion of typing in the console, as in key events register without GUI, without actually needing to type in the console)

Comment: I looked into raw mode... and it seems like it is fairly nonportable.  Is there a way to get an applet that just hides itself but can still use the keyevents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution!

I just built an applet that renders text!

here's the code if your intererested

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class _Newmain extends Canvas {
    private static int renderSizeX = 25;
    private static int renderSizeY = 25;

    private point player = new point(10,10,'X');
    public _Newmain() {
        setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){
                @Override
                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
                    moveIt(evt);
                }
            });
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        String text = m2.outputScreen(new point[]{player});
        int x = 20; int y = 20;
        for (String line : text.split("\n"))
            g.drawString(line, x, y += g.getFontMetrics().getHeight());
        //g.drawString(m2.outputScreen(new point[]{player}), 20, 20);
    }

    public void moveIt(KeyEvent evt) {
        switch (evt.getKeyCode()) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
            player.moveY(1);
            break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
            player.moveY(-1);
            break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
            player.moveX(-1);
            break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
            player.moveX(1);
            break;
        }

        repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TEXT BASED GAME WRITTEN BY SHANE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        _Newmain ex = new _Newmain();
        frame.getContentPane().add(ex);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        ex.requestFocus();

    }
}
```