# Java Scanner: stop reading after the first entry

Tags: java, input, keyboard, java.util.scanner

Im looking for a form to make *Scanner* to stop reading when you push the first time (so, if I press the key *K* automatically the program considerer that I press the *Intro* key, so it stop to recognise inputs, save the *K* and keep going with the program).

Im using **char key= sc.next().charAt(0);** in a beginning, but dont know how to make it stop without pushing *Intro*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you mean by push? are you just trying to read in 1 line from the user?

Comment: No, just the key the user push in the keyboard

Comment: @Frikilangelo Did you find a solution to your problem?

Comment: Not yet... For now Im working in other parts, dont want to stop in one thing because I cant find a solution

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stop accepting after a single particular character you should read the user's input character by character. Try scanning based on a [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) of one single character or using the [Console](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) class.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
Pattern oneChar = new Pattern(".{1}");
// make sure DOTALL is true so you capture the Enter key
String input = scanner.next(oneChar);
StringBuilder allChars = new StringBuilder();

// while input is not the Enter key {
    if (input.equals("K")) {
        // break out of here
    } else {
        // add the char to allChars and wait for the next char
    }
    input = scanner.next(oneChar);
}
// the Enter key or "K" was pressed - process 'allChars'
```

Comment: Pattern is new to me, I will take a look to it, looks like im missing something because the **new Pattern(".{1}");** part is asking me for another int argument

Comment: Try *Pattern scanner =  Pattern.compile(".{1}");*

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Java doesn't support non blocking console and hence, you can't read user's input character by character (read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066318/how-to-read-a-single-char-from-the-console-in-java-as-the-user-types-it) SO answer for more details).

However, what you can do is, you can ask the user to enter the whole line and process each character of it until *Intro* is encountered, below is an example:

```
System.out.println("Enter the input");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = scanner.nextLine();
StringBuilder processedChars = new StringBuilder();
for(int i=0 ; i<input.length() ; i++){
    char c = input.charAt(i);
    if(c == 'K' || c == 'k'){
        break;
    }else{
        processedChars.append(c);
    }
}
System.out.println(processedChars.toString());
```

Comment: Is sad to hear that; what I wanted is the same you do there, but automatically to avoid the "extra key push". Perhaps someday we can have that option