# How to validate each input character based on following conditions

Tags: java, performance, validation, optimization, boggle

I am developing a Boggle game. I want to validate two things on key press/up/down etc.

1. Using keyboard, a user should be restricted to only enter character that is in the board (and append it to input string/word) else skip it. Boggle board of 4 x 4 is shown to user. For example

   ```
   A B B A
   A A B B
   B B A A
   A B A B
   ```

   In this case C - Z are invalid inputs, they should not be appended to the input string, I want user to press ENTER key only once when it has entered complete word.
2. Entered character must be adjacent (vertically, horizontally or diagonally) to previous character.

At the moment I am taking a string using scanner (`system.in`) and validating these conditions using two separate functions, but I want on spot validation.

My code:

```
package com.boggle;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class BoggleBoard {
    String[] Cons = {"B","C","D","F","G","H","J","K","L","M",
                    "N","P","Q","R","S","T","V","W","X","Y","Z"};
    String[] Vow = {"A","E","I","O","U"};
    String[][] board = new String[4][4];
    String[] adjcntStr = new String[16];
    boolean[] ConsMark = new boolean[21];
    String Bstring = "";
    boolean isValid;
    Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    public void ShowNear(){
    for(int i=0; i<16; i++){
        cout(adjcntStr[i]+"\n");
        }
    }   
    public void Play(){
        cout("Enter Your Word\n");
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);  
        String xYz = read.next();
        if(!ValidChar(xYz))
        {
            cout("Invalid Choice\n");
            Play();
        }
        else
        {
            if(!ValidSqnc(xYz, 0))          
            {
                cout("\nInvalid Sequence\n");
                Play();
            }
            else
            {
                cout("\n\nWord: "+xYz);
            }           
        }
        read.close();
    }
    public boolean ValidChar(String t){
        for(int i = 0; i<t.length();i++){
            if(!Bstring.contains(""+t.charAt(i)+"")){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    public boolean ValidSqnc(String S, int i){
        if(i+1 == S.length())
        {
            isValid = true;
            return true;
            }
        if(adjcntStr[Bstring.indexOf(Character.toString(S.charAt(i)))].contains(Character.toString(S.charAt(i+1))))
        {
            ValidSqnc(S, ++i);
        }
        else
        {           
            isValid = false;
        }
        return isValid;
    }
    public void cout(String T){
        System.out.print(T);
    }
    public String GetStr(){
        return Bstring;
    }
    public BoggleBoard(){
                setBoard();
                getBoard();
                near();
            }
    public void setBoard(){
        int c=0;
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){   
            for(int j=0;j<4;j++){               
                if( (int)rand.nextInt(2)==0 && c<5){
                    board[i][j] = Vow[c];
                    Bstring = Bstring + Vow[c];
                    ++c;
                }
                else
                {
                    board[i][j]= Cons[UniqueInt()];
                    Bstring = Bstring + board[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public int UniqueInt(){
        int index;
        while(true)
        {
            index = (int)(rand.nextInt(21));
            if(ConsMark[index]==false)
            {
                ConsMark[index] = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return index;
 }
    public void getBoard(){
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
            for(int f=0;f<4;f++){
                    cout(board[i][f]+" ");
            }
                    System.out.println();           
        }
    }
    public void near(){     
        int row = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
                adjcntStr[row] =  "";
                for (int x = Math.max(0, i - 1); x <= Math.min(i + 1, board.length); x++) {
                    for (int y = Math.max(0, j - 1); y <= Math.min(j + 1,
                            board[i].length); y++) {
                        if (x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < board.length
                                && y < board[i].length) {
                            if(x!=i || y!=j){                            
                            adjcntStr[row] = adjcntStr[row] + board[x][y];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                row++;
            }
        }       
    }
```

In short, I have no repeated characters in board, I am maintaining a adjacency string for each index location and a string of all board characters, I use `indexof()` to get index of character in board, then look up in adjacency string[] for the validity.

Comment: Post your code and explain your exact difficulties.

Comment: @PM77-1 the procedure is very difficult, will simple copy paste work?

Comment: You need to provide enough information to show us what you have accomplished so far and where exactly you are stuck.  Plain code dump would not be helpful.

Comment: There are several solutions; which one would be most appropriate would depend on what approach you are taking.  A console application might read from `System.in`, where as a Swing application would use `addKeyListener()` to process individual keypresses.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read a single char from the console in Java (as the user types it)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066318/how-to-read-a-single-char-from-the-console-in-java-as-the-user-types-it)