# How do I assign values with a scanner while simultaneously printing a single line?

Tags: java, int, java.util.scanner, variable-assignment

I'm trying to make something that looks like this:

`Move # to #`. For example, `Move 1 to 3`

I tried `System.out.print("move " + input.nextInt() + " to " + input.nextInt())`

This works fine, but I don't know how to assign values from those inputs.

This works, but it's NOT what I want:

```
System.out.print("move ");
int first = input.nextInt();
System.out.print(" to ");
int second = input.nextInt();
```

I don't want this, because instead of `move # to #`, it gives this:

```
move #
to #
```

How can I keep all inputs in a single line while still assigning the input values to variables?

In order, I want the line to look like this:

before first input:

```
Move _
```

after first input:

```
Move # to _
```

after second input:

```
Move # to #
```

Comment: @shmosel I want `to` to appear after the first input, but before the second input. So simply pressing space would do nothing.

Comment: I take that back. But your question is confusing. The first example implies you want to input both values before printing them out. The second implies you want to input them inline with your output. Which is it?

Comment: @shmosel I edited the second example to re-state that it's what I DON'T want. I want the first, not the second.

Comment: The implication was that the only issue in the second example is the newline. If you don't mind inputting and then printing, just do `System.out.print("move " + first + " to " + second);`.

Comment: @shmosel Finding a way to print while inputting is actually the whole point of the question.

Comment: Now you're going back to the second way... Anyway, I think I understand now. Unfortunately I suspect there's no easy way to do what you want.

Comment: Note that a computer program rarely does two things "simultaneously", especially at a beginner level. This is probably just a poor choice of words, but I wanted to point it out for clarification.

Comment: @shmosel Are you suggesting it's impossible to gain the stored values illustrated in the second way while also keeping things to a single line?

Comment: @shmosel Thank you for all your help with refining my questions, by the way! I actually have a bad habit of wording things in a confusing manner.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I assume it's a poor choice of words. In a way... I guess I'm just asking how I can execute something like `int variable = Scanner.nextInt()` without it adding a new line.

Comment: I think you'll need something like this: [How to read a single char from the console in Java (as the user types it)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066318/how-to-read-a-single-char-from-the-console-in-java-as-the-user-types-it)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Scanner` reads input until the user presses Enter which inserts a newline character into the buffer. This character will be printed and cause the next output to appear on the next line. I don't think you can do what you want with `Scanner`. You will need to use a `InputStream` or `Reader` class instead.

Comment: How can `InputStream` or `Reader`  run something equivalent to `int variable = Scanner.nextInt()` without a newline?

Comment: @MarkPuchalaII With a lot more work on your part. One way is to read each character one at a time yourself and then convert the input into a number. Since you read each character, you can use something other than the newline, such as a space, as a delimiter.