# Reading one word at a time from console in java

Tags: java, multithreading, input

is there a way in Java to read input from console one word at a time? As in when user presses a space I want to take whatever word he typed before it and add it to a collection for example.

I've tried using Scanner, but it only allows me to read words after the end of a line (enter key press).

*Context: It's a school project and teacher wants us to make a program that reads users input in one thread and displays list of words and their count from the input in another thread. And he wants the list updated after **every new word** is typed...*

Comment: Are you simply trying to accept multiple command line arguments i.e. “java Foo a b c”?

Comment: I don’t have experience with the console, but I would use “args” in the main function to access the arguments array and loop through it and add each argument to my collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that via the console unless you put the console into character mode, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1066647/6391367

However I very much doubt that your teacher expects you to do that.

The two options I see are:

1. Your teacher expects you to press enter after each word (check your spec carefully, or just ask them)
2. Your teacher expects you to create a GUI using Swing / JavaFX where the user inputs text. Using a key listener you could then read this input character by character.

Comment: Yeah, this is likely. The assignment description is very vague. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to read a single word from the console using Scanner. For example:

```
Scanner input = new  Scanner(System.in);
   String word;

    System.out.println("Enter word(s)");

    while(input.hasNext()){
    word = input.next();
    System.out.println(word);
    }
```