# How to implement keypress in java?

Tags: java, console

How to make that the user has pressed any key and the system automatically did get the value and save him in variable (without pressing Enter)? 
In console.

Comment: I don't think this is possible without JNI (native code).  Java console IO is simple and line oriented, it doen't provide full terminal access.

Comment: This type of reading from console called raw. You can do this character by character. here is one solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066318/how-to-read-a-single-char-from-the-console-in-java-as-the-user-types-it

Comment: I recommend you to look for a solution that match with your system. Like Windows or Mac. Because this type of things is an OS shell dependent.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  I suggest that you look at the Linked question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066318/how-to-read-a-single-char-from-the-console-in-java-as-the-user-types-it, and if that answers your question, then close this question.