# Is there a way to print text after the line where the user inputs?

Tags: java

I'm looking to print text on a line that is AFTER where the user is inputing their text.

```
String userInput;

System.out.println("Hello");
userInput = In.getString();
//I want a System.out.print(""); right here, but I want it to appear while 
//the user is still typing their input.
```

Print: "Hello"

*User is getting input*

Print "I am printing this at the same time that the user is typing"

Comment: Main thread cannot do concurrency execution, you need two threads that run concurrently to do this

Comment: Write a [Java Swing](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-swing) GUI application.  Create a text field.  Write a Key listener to intercept keystrokes typed into the text field.  Create a second text field.  For every key detected by the listener, echo the corresponding character into the second text field.  Easy Peasy ;)  Doing something in line-oriented text mode in Java, without [curses](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/): not so much...

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, keystrokes cannot be captured in raw java console applications.

His could be do e using gui applications like using `AWT/Swing GUI`.

Since this could be an overkill for your problem, you should know that java suports editing of console outputs in a way.

E.g. if the current output has `hello`, printing `\b` character will erase one character from console and it will look like `hell`.

Perhaps you can think in these lines and build your functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can put console into raw mode. There is no built-in platform-independent way of getting there. This might be a solution you can implement,

[Non blocking console input in Python and Java](https://www.darkcoding.net/software/non-blocking-console-io-is-not-possible/)

got it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066318/how-to-read-a-single-char-from-the-console-in-java-as-the-user-types-it). There are more solutions in there that might be helpful