# How to read input while the user is still typing in java?

Tags: java, input

I want to read the input in java while it is being typed. I think node js has this facility but not java

Comment: Where is the user typing?

Comment: Possibly [relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066318/how-to-read-a-single-char-from-the-console-in-java-as-the-user-types-it)