# print on the same line after a scanneroutput

Tags: java

here is my simple question:...
How can I eliminate the 'nextline' after a scanner output?

```java
System.out.println("Player 1: Rock (1), Paper (2) or Scissors?(3)");

int p1 = input.nextInt();

if (p1 == 1) {
    System.out.print("= rock\n");
} else if (p1 == 2) {
    System.out.print("= paper\n");
} else {
    System.out.print("= scissors\n");
}
```

outcome:

> **Player 1: Rock (1), Paper (2) or Scissors?(3)**
>
> *1*
>
> **= rock**

desired outcome

> **Player 1: Rock (1), Paper (2) or Scissors?(3)**
>
> *1*   **= rock**

Thanks to you all

Comment: I don't think it's possible as you are pressing `Enter` for `Scanner` to scan your input.

Answer (score 0):

With nextInt() you have to press enter so I don't think you can
Maybe look at other ways to get an input such as:
System.in.read()

[(Java) How to get user input without pressing the "enter" key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59742483/java-how-to-get-user-input-without-pressing-the-enter-key)