# Java get user input while user is typing (no raw mode)

Tags: java

I am making a Java program that get arrow keys and characters as input without pressing enter, I have searched the web, and the only "solution" was putting the TTY in raw mode. I do not want to do that, since that does not work on windows.

EDIT: I am read from the console. Scanner and System.in does not return data until Enter is pressed.

Comment: I think This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18037576/how-do-i-check-if-the-user-is-pressing-a-key is what your looking for.

Comment: I am reading from the console, or STDIN

Comment: Maybe this can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59742483/java-how-to-get-user-input-without-pressing-the-enter-key

Comment: Unfortunately, that link and the duplacate link as well mention using "raw mode", which I clearly dont want.

Comment: The problem is that you are wanting to do a very low-level operating system function. Java isn't good at that because it can't be done in a way that is consistent across platforms. Most gui frameworks can do this because they do interface with the os at that level, but console input doesn't.

Comment: is there a "raw mode" for windows?