# get char of VK_ key

Tags: java, keyevent

In a method i'm receiving `vk_key`'s as just a `int`, nothing more is provided.

I need to forward this, which looks like:

```
parent.postEvent(new KeyEvent(null, parent.millis(), KeyEvent.TYPE, modiefiers, c_key, vk_key));
```

The problem is there are also things like `VK_UP`, `VK_DOWN` etc.
Where normally I need to do a cast: `char c_key = (char)vk_key;`, this is incorrect for `VK_UP` etc. cause the cast will make the up key a '&' for example.
For those cases the c_key should be set to `KeyEvent.CHAR_UNDEFINED`.

What I do now is this:

```
switch (vk_key) {
    case VK_UP: 
    case VK_LEFT:
    case VK_RIGHT:
    case VK_DOWN:
    c_key = CHAR_UNDEFINED;
    break;
}
```

But this does not feel like the right way to do it.
Ideally there would have been a static method like `static public char getCharForKey(int vk_key)`, which would return `CHAR_UNDEFINED` where required. But as always oracle makes things way harder then they should be.

So is there any easy way to figure out if something should be `CHAR_UNDEFINED` or not?

Comment: Where are you getting a naked `vk_key` code from? Usually you only get them from `KeyEvent`s... Also note: if the component is `null` the [KeyEvent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#KeyEvent(java.awt.Component,%20int,%20long,%20int,%20int,%20char)) constructor will throw an `IllegalArgumentException`

Comment: Simply receive the event instead of creating one, then call this on the event: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getKeyChar()

Comment: @BeyelerStudios I get them from a terminal that is set in a mode that no return key is required, I use `System.in.read()` and map them to the right `VK_KEY` where required. For example when I press the up key, the terminal will create the sequence `27 91 65` and I know that is VK_UP.

Comment: `char c_key = (char)vk_key;` is *not* valid.  There are no guarantees that a keycode will be equal to its corresponding char value.  The only way to obtain a char value from a key press is by listening for [keyTyped](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html#keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent)) events and reading the value with [getKeyChar](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getKeyChar()).

Comment: @VGR I can't listen for keyTyped events, cause it is the terminal that has focus and not the java application.

Comment: If the terminal sends 65 by itself, that is not a key code;  it’s already a character.  The VK_* constants in KeyEvent only apply to KeyEvents.  You are free to map escape sequences to control keys;  that is in fact what terminfo databases do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a single char from the console in Java (as the user types it)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066318/how-to-read-a-single-char-from-the-console-in-java-as-the-user-types-it)

Comment: @BeyelerStudios I have no problem reading the chars. I only have problems forwarding the char I readed to processing (processing.org) as if it where a real event.

Comment: Since you're using `System.in.read()` you're not getting `VK`-KeyCodes (see [read](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read())). As it stands your question poses an [xy-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). What you want to achieve was already asked in [How to read a single char from the console in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066318/how-to-read-a-single-char-from-the-console-in-java-as-the-user-types-it) look at the proposed solutions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30008252/3426025) or particularize your question.