# Why does it run 3 times before asking for user input again?

Tags: java

It works fine with '1'but with the other options it runs 3x times (by printing out the whole Menu
thing before allowing user input again.

```
char a; 
    
    do { 
    System.out.println ("MENU");
    System.out.println ("Press 1 to EXIT");
    System.out.println ("Press 2 to PLAY");
    System.out.println ("Press 3 for SETTINGS");
    a = (char)System.in.read();
    switch (a){
    
    case '1': 
        System.out.println ("You have EXITED");
        break;
    case '2':
        System.out.println ("GAME OVER");
        break;
    case '3':
        System.out.println ("You chose SETTINGS");
        break;
    }
    
    }while (a != '1');
```

Answer (score 1):

By default the console (or similar) is line buffered, so you type a digit followed by return/enter. You are reading a character at a time. The three characters you see are the digit, Carriage Return (CR/`'\r'`) and New Line (NL/`'\n'`).

See this question [How to read a single char from the console in Java (as the user types it)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1066318/4725) Alternatively read a line at a time - most example programs will use `java.util.Scanner`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to reset the a as '1'. The reason it was executing repeatedly is because the value of as is not reset