# Why do I have to press enter while running to end the program?

Tags: java

I am making a code for a project. When I input for example

```
Harry + John
Harry * James
finish
```

The output should be

```
HarryJohn
HarryHarryHarryHarryHarry
End
```

However, my current output is

```
HarryJohn
HarryHarryHarryHarryHarry

End
```

I have to press enter in order for the program to print "End" and finish. Is there any way for me to not press enter in order to finish running my code?

The following is the code I have written so far.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str1 = in.next();
    while (!str1.equals("finish")) {
        String op = in.next();
        String str2 = in.next();
        if (op.equals("+")){
            System.out.println(str1 + str2);
        }
        else if (op.equals("*")){
            for (int i = 0; i < str2.length(); i++){
                System.out.print(str1);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("wrong");
        }
        String blankStr = in.nextLine();
        str1 = in.next();
    }
    System.out.println("End");
}
```

Comment: Debugger/IDE is the tool to resolve problems like this

Comment: Does [How to read a single char from the console in Java (as the user types it)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066318/how-to-read-a-single-char-from-the-console-in-java-as-the-user-types-it) helps you?

Comment: Actually I already tried debugging using the Debugger, but I failed to see the problem. I also think this is a different problem from what J.F. has suggested.

Comment: Consider adding a space after "finish " in input

Answer (score 0):

Because while loop is running one more time as the contdition is not checked before the loop begins,so it will run an extra time then check the c