# Kotlin how do I stop the program with the response output on the screen?

Tags: kotlin

I have an endless cycle going on. How do I stop the program to output the answer? The meaning of my program: reads all characters (including enter) and outputs the sum of only numbers.

```
fun main() {
fun StrToSum(str: String): Long {
    var sum : Long = 0
    var next = ""
    for (symbol in str + " ") {
        if (symbol == '-') {
            if ((next != "-") && (next != "")) {
                sum += next!!.toLong()
            }
            next = symbol.toString()
        } else if (symbol.isDigit()) {
            next += symbol
        } else if (next != "") {
            if (next != "-") {
                sum += next!!.toLong()
            }
            next = ""
        }
    }
    return sum
}

var string: String = ""

while (1<2) { //How stop it ?
    var str = readLine()!!.toString()
    string += " " + str
}
println (StrToSum(string)) //answer
```

}
maybe there is some kind of keyboard shortcut ? I work for IntelliJ from Jetbrains

Answer (score 0):

You can *terminate* the currently running program, but that will kill it - it won't be able to output the answer. You need to code that handling as part of your design, so you *enable* the user to finish and print your result.

The usual way people do this is to have some kind of *cancel* input, like entering an `x` or something:

```
// while (true) is a typical way to create an infinite loop
while (true) {
    var str = readLine()!!.toString()
    // look for the cancel token, break out of the loop if you see it
    if (str.lowercase() == "x") break
    string += " " + str
}
```

If you don't want to do that (remember you can make the cancel token anything, like the word `"cancel"` if you like, and put a prompt on the screen telling the user to type it to finish) then you'd have to do something like detecting other keycodes like *Ctrl+Z* or whatever - and I'm not sure how you'd do that from a basic command-line program reading from standard input. Maybe someone knows some tricks you could use! It's not something I've ever had to do, so I can't help you there

---

*edit* If you're happy to just look for [control characters like `^D`](https://www.aivosto.com/articles/control-characters.html) in the lines of standard input, you could do this kind of thing

```
if (str.firstOrNull().code == 4) break // char value for ^D
```

But that still requires the user to press *Enter* after the *Ctrl+D*, so the line including that character can be sent from the terminal to standard input. That's just how it works, outside of the [solutions in the discussion I linked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1066318/13598222) which involve OS-level interaction or building a GUI so you have access to the raw keypresses.

Comment: I'm sorry I answered late, but your method doesn't work, I need a keyboard shortcut ctrl+D

Comment: @SudarKudr like I said, reading raw keypresses like that isn't something that standard input handles - usually you type a line into your console, press enter, and then that line is passed to your `Scanner`, your `readLine()` etc. There's a discussion about reading keystrokes in Java (and by extension in Kotlin) here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1066318/13598222 I don't know much about it, but it looks like you either need to hook into the operating system's API using a library, or build yourself a GUI and grab the keystrokes from that

Comment: @SudarKudr I've added an example for identifying control characters in your input - but that still requires the user pressing Enter after the Ctrl+D, because that's how your input in the terminal is sent to standard input for your app to consume