# How to end loop by input in java

Tags: java

Hi I want to end loop when q was input.

So I made a code below

```
        System.out.println("press q to end the loop");
        String endLoop = "";
        while(!endLoop.equals("q")) {
            endLoop = sc.next();
            System.out.println(num);
            num++;
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
```

The code I made have some problem.
My code wait for user to input every time. But I don't want to wait for input every repeat.
I just want to catch when user input q by keyboard. And then I want to end the loop.

What should I do to solve this problem??

Comment: Try `do { ... } while(!endLoop.equals("q"));`, i.e. evaluate the input at the end. Or just use an endless loop and use `if(endLoop.equals("q")) { break; }` to end the loop.

Comment: "q" and enter or just "q"?

Comment: "q" enter. I want to catch a moment when q + enter is pressed

Comment: What do you mean you want to catch that moment? What do you expect to happen here? You expect the loop to keep incrementing and printing `num` even if you don't press anything and then exit if you press "q" and then enter?

Comment: Yes exactly!! I wanted google and find by my self but I don't know the keyword

Comment: Then see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1066647/133203 TL;DR: there's no portable way of doing this.

Answer (score -1):

You can take a flag, initializing with true, and after the first input is taken, change it to false.